# Adding Dataset into XML Document as a parameter to webservice

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I have created a Web Service method which takes a `Dataset` as a parameter and have to send parameters in the form of `XMLDocument` not use any other way the code below:

```
public static bool UpdateUnitMst(string isLive, string EmpId, string EmpNameFull, DataSet dst, string where)
{
    XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = new XmlDocument();
    string xmlToLoad = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
                        <soap:Envelope 
                                    xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" 
                                    xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
                                    xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
                        <soap:Body>
                        <UpdateUnitMst xmlns=""http://abc/services/"">"
                            + "<isLive>" + isLive + "</isLive>"
                            + "<EmpId>" + EmpId + "</EmpId>"
                            + "<EmpNameFull>" + EmpNameFull + "</EmpNameFull>"
                            + "<dst>" + dst + "</dst>"
                            + "<where>" + where + "</where>"
                    + "</UpdateUnitMst>"
                    + "</soap:Body>"
                    + "</soap:Envelope>";
    soapEnvelopeXml.LoadXml(xmlToLoad);
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = GetWebRequest();
        using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
        }
        using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                string xmlString = rd.ReadToEnd();
                XmlDocument soapResult = new XmlDocument();
                soapResult.LoadXml(xmlString);

                string result = soapResult.GetElementsByTagName("UpdateUnitMstResult")[0].InnerText;

                if (result != "success")
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
    return true;
}
```

Please help me I am stuck for a couple of days.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can call `GetXml` method on your `DataSet` to get a `string` representation of the data stored in the `DataSet`.Then at your service method you can convert it back to a `DataSet` object by calling `ReadXml` of `DataSet`.

Comment: [Returning DataSets from a publically accessible Web Service is a BAD IDEA](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReturningDataSetsFromWebServicesIsTheSpawnOfSatanAndRepresentsAllThatIsTrulyEvilInTheWorld.aspx) and doing webservice calls by manually sending XML is probably at the same level. There is a reason you are struggling with the technical side: it's not meant to be used that way. Describe your problem and there wil probably be a *way* better solution.

Comment: Your post had formatting mistakes. I corrected them. Your edit made it worse. Please don't guess what your text will look like, use the preview window before you post text here. You can also rollback your whole edit.

Comment: I have used GetXml method to convert dataset into string but it becomes a huge string and my mehod return bad request 400 error.

Comment: MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            ds.WriteXml(stream);